# Facing "Operation failed. Retry count remains = 1" error in DBeaver

Tags: java, jdbc

I've encountered an error while using DBeaver:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ko
Framework arguments:  -eclipse.keyring C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\secure\secure_storage
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model
Error
Mon Sep 25 14:09:32 KST 2023
Operation failed. Retry count remains = 1
```

Upon troubleshooting this issue, I've noted:

I initially suspected a compatibility issue between Java and DBeaver, but version 17.0.6 should be compatible.
I've checked DBeaver's log files for further insights but couldn't find any additional relevant information.
I haven't installed any plugins or extensions, so I doubt it's an issue related to that.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions for resolution, I'd greatly appreciate your input. Thank you!

You can post this on Stack Overflow, and hopefully, the community will provide you with the necessary guidance or solutions.

board

```
package org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class Board{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false) // content를 TEXT 타입으로 설정하고 NOT NULL 제약 조건 추가
    private  String content;

    @Column(length = 15000 )
    private String filename;

    @Column(length = 30000 )
    private String filepath;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name="user_no")
    private Member member;
}
```

boardDTO

```
        package org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.dto;

        import lombok.Builder;
        import lombok.Data;
        import lombok.Getter;
        import lombok.Setter;
        import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.BaseEntity;

        import java.util.Date;

        @Data
        @Builder
        public class BoardDto {

            @Setter@Getter
            private int id;
            private String title;
            private String content;
            private String filename;
            private String filepath;
            private Date createdAt;
            private String memberNick; // 회원 닉네임

            // 생성자, getter, setter 생략
        }
```

boardrepository

```
package org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.repository;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.Board;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.Member;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BoardRepository  extends JpaRepository <Board, Integer> {
}
```

BoardService

```
    package org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.service;

    import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
    import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.dto.BoardDto;
    import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.Board;
    import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.Member;
    import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.repository.BoardRepository;
    import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.repository.member.MemberRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;



    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class BoardService {



            @Autowired
            private BoardRepository boardRepository;

            @Autowired
            private MemberRepository memberRepository;


            //게시글 리스트 처리
            public Page<Board>boardList(Pageable pageable){

                return boardRepository.findAll(pageable);


            }
            //특정 게시글 불러오기
        public Board boardView(Integer id) {

                Board board = boardRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

            return board;

        }
        //특정게시글 삭제
        public void boardDelete(Integer id){

                boardRepository.deleteById(id);
        }

        // 게시글 작성 메서드
        public BoardDto write(Board board, MultipartFile file, String userId) throws Exception {
            Member member = memberRepository.findByUserId(userId).orElse(null);

            if (board.getContent() != null && !board.getContent().isEmpty()) {
    //            // 생성 날짜 설정
    //            board.setCreatedAt(new Date());
                // 파일 저장 경로 설정
                String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/static/files";
                // UUID를 사용하여 파일명 중복 방지
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

                // 파일이 업로드되었을 때만 파일 처리
                if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
                    String fileName = uuid + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
                    File saveFile = new File(projectPath, fileName);
                    file.transferTo(saveFile);
                    board.setFilename(fileName);
                    board.setFilepath("/files/" + fileName); // 파일 경로 동적 설정
                }
                board.setMember(member);

                Board savedBoard = boardRepository.saveAndFlush(board); // 데이터베이스에 저장save(board)

                // 게시글과 회원 닉네임을 포함한 DTO 객체 생성
                BoardDto boardDto = BoardDto.builder()
                                .title(savedBoard.getTitle())
                                        .content(savedBoard.getContent())
                                                .filepath(savedBoard.getFilepath())
                                                        .filename(savedBoard.getFilename())
                                                                .build();
                boardDto.setMemberNick(member.getUserNick());

                return boardDto;
            } else {
                // 콘텐츠가 null 또는 비어 있을 경우 예외 처리
                throw new Exception("게시물 내용을 입력해주세요.");
            }
        }
        }
```

BoardController

```
package org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.controller;


import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.dto.BoardDto;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.entity.Board;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.security.JwtTokenProvider;
import org.polyproject.fishinghubpro.service.BoardService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class BoardController {


    @Autowired
    private BoardService boardService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @GetMapping("/board/log")
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkLogin(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) {
        // "Bearer " 접두어 제거 (토큰이 "Bearer [토큰값]" 형식으로 오는 경우)
        token = token.startsWith("Bearer ") ? token.substring(7) : token;

        // 토큰 유효성 검사
        if (jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("User is logged in");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Unauthorized");
        }
    }
    @GetMapping("/board/write")//localhost:8090/board/write
    public String boardWriteForm(){

        return "boardwrite";
    }

    //원본
    @PostMapping("board/writepro")//@RequestBodyboard앞에
    public ResponseEntity<BoardDto> boardWritePro(Board board,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) throws Exception {
        String userId = principal.getName();

        // boardService.write 메서드로 게시글을 작성하고 게시글 정보를 받아옴
        BoardDto createdBoard = boardService.write(board, file, userId);

        System.out.println("board : "+board+", id : "+userId);
        System.out.println("board : "+board+", file : "+file+", id : "+userId);
        // ResponseEntity로 커스텀 응답을 생성하고, 상태 코드와 함께 반환
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdBoard, HttpStatus.CREATED); // 수정: response 대신 createdBoard 반환
    }





@GetMapping("/board/list")
public ResponseEntity<List<Board>> boardList(@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10, sort = "id", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Board> list = boardService.boardList(pageable);

    // 게시글 목록을 리스트로 변환
    List<Board> boardList = list.getContent();

    // ResponseEntity를 사용하여 JSON 형식으로 데이터 반환
    return new ResponseEntity<>(boardList, HttpStatus.OK);
}

    @GetMapping("/board/view")//localhost:8080/board/view?id=1
    public String boardView(Model model, Integer id){


        model.addAttribute("board",boardService.boardView(id));
        return "boardview";
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/board/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteBoard(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        try {
            // 게시글 삭제를 시도합니다.
            boardService.boardDelete(id);

            // 게시글이 성공적으로 삭제되었을 때의 응답입니다.
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // 게시글 삭제 중 오류가 발생했을 때의 응답입니다.
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("게시글 삭제 중 오류가 발생했습니다.");
        }
    }


//    @GetMapping("/board/delete")
//        public String boardDelete(Integer id){
//
//            boardService.boardDelete(id);
//
//            return "redirect:/board/list";
//        }



    @GetMapping("/board/modify/{id}")
    public String boardModify(@PathVariable("id")Integer id,Model model){

        model.addAttribute("board",boardService.boardView(id));
        return "boardmodify";
    }
    @PostMapping("/board/update/")
    public String boardUpdate(@RequestBody BoardDto board, Principal principal)throws Exception {
        log.info("지나갑니다!~!==={}",board.getId());
        String userId = principal.getName();    //게시글을 쓴 애의 아이디.
        Board boardTemp = boardService.boardView(board.getId());   //기존에 저장된 게시글 가져오기

        //기존에 저장된 게시글에 새로 들어온 데이터로 수정 해주는 구문.
        boardTemp.setTitle(board.getTitle());   //dirtyChecking으로 변경감지로 수정. 따로 저장 구문 필요 없음.
        boardTemp.setContent(board.getContent());
//        boardService.write(boardTemp, file, userId); // 수정된 내용을 저장
        return "수정되었습니다.";
    }

}
```

DBeaver Error with Retry Count on Windows
I attempted to run DBeaver with my usual configurations.
I was expecting DBeaver to start and operate as usual without any hitches.
Instead, I encountered an error message that states:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ko
Framework arguments: -eclipse.keyring C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\secure\secure_storage
Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model
오류
Mon Sep 25 14:09:32 KST 2023
Operation failed. Retry count remains = 1
```

Any assistance in understanding and resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please remove salutations/thanks from your question as per the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. Also the paragraph "You can post this on Stack Overflow,..." is superfluous and should be removed.

Comment: What is the relationship of the source code shared with the DBeaver issue? What are the symptoms of the error? What are the steps for reproduction? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).